# Error while trying to pass query to database with PHP (data from HTML form)

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

**EDIT: problem has now been solved, ive provided my original and my fixed versions of the PHP code below. honestly not sure what the difference is, i've never used PHP before but hopefully this helps someone!**

looking for some help.
i'm doing university coursework at the moment and need help with one element.
when i am trying to pass data which is taken in from a web form, the page gives an error if i use the following statement:

```
    echo $db_connection->error;
```

the error that it gives is:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$useremail' (T_VARIABLE) in (directory goes here, i've removed it)
```

i cant figure out how to fix this error. if i echo the SQL insert query and copy+paste it into the database it works perfectly.

any help would be much appreciated.

edit:
the fixed full PHP code is as follows:

```
        <?php

require_once "db.php";
    // below code checks whether the form is submitted
    // using the POST method or not

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // the form is submitted using the POST method
        // now proceed to process the form's data

        //$errPass = $errEmail = $errName = $errCVtype = $errCompanyname = "";
        //$pass = $email = $name = $usercomment = $cvtype = $companyname = "";

        //$pass           = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, 
$_POST["password"]);

       // $salt = "TheQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheMoonTwice";
       // $data = $pass . $salt;
        //$password = crypt($data);
        //these commented lines are redundant (left in by lecturer)

        $useremail      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["email"]);
        $fname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["fname"]);
        $sname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["sname"]);
        $cname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["cname"]);
        $usercomment    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["comment"]);
        $cvtype         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["cvchoice"]);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP and MySQLi Thank you message.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/process_cv.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="text-field">
            <section>
<?php 


    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" )
    {

        $qry = "insert into cv_test(email, fname, sname, cname, usercomment, cvrequested)
                values('$useremail', '$fname', '$sname', '$cname', '$usercomment', '$cvtype');";
        $res = $db_connection->query($qry);
        if($res)
        {   
            echo "<p id='Title'>Thank you for requesting to see my CV.</p>";
            echo "<p id='Name'>Your Name: <strong>".$fname."</strong></p>";
            echo "<p id='Email'>Your Email: <strong>".$useremail."</strong></p>";
            echo "<p id='Company'>Your Company Name: <strong>".$cname."</strong></p>";
            echo "<p id='Comment'>Your Comment: ".$usercomment."</p>";
            echo "<p id='CV'><a href='REMOVED PRIVATE URL";

            if ($cvtype === 'short') 
                echo "Short_CV";
            else
                echo "Long_CV";
            echo ".pdf' target='_blank'>View my ".$cvtype." CV</a></p>";
            //echo "<p id='image_map'><a href='../image_map.html'>Return To Image_Map</a></p>";
            exit();
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<p>Error occurred, kindly try again later.</p>";
            //echo "<p><a href='../image_map.html'>Return To Image_Map</a></p>";
            exit();
        }

    }

$db_connection->close();    
?>
     </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the original code was:

```
        <?php

require_once "db.php";
    // below code checks whether the form is submitted
    // using the POST method or not

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // the form is submitted using the POST method
        // now proceed to process the form's data

        //$errPass = $erruseremail = $errfname = $errsname = $errcname = $errusercomment = $errcvtype = "";
        //$pass = $useremail = $fname = $sname = $cname = $usercomment = $cvtype = "";

        //$pass           = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["password"]);

        //$salt = "TheQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheMoonTwice";
        //$data = $pass . $salt;
        //$password = crypt($data);

        $useremail      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["email"]);
        $fname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["fname"]);
        $sname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["sname"]);
        $cname          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["cname"]);
        $usercomment    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["comment"]);
        $cvtype         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST["cvchoice"]);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP and MySQLi Thank you message.</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $qry = "insert into cv_test(email, fname, sname, cname, usercomment, cvrequested)<br>
                values('$useremail', '$fname', '$sname', '$cname', '$usercomment', '$cvtype');";
        echo $qry . "<br>";
        $res = $db_connection->query($qry);
        if($res)
        {
            echo "<p>Thank you for requesting to see my CV.</p>";
            echo "<p> Your name: <strong>".$fname." ".$sname."</strong></p>";
            echo "<p>Your Company Name: <strong>".$cname."</strong></p>";
            echo "<p>Your email: ".$useremail."</p>";
            echo "<p>Your Comment: ".$usercomment."</p>";
            echo "<p><a href='REMOVED PRIVATE URL";

            if ($cvtype === 'short') 
                echo "Short_CV";
            else
                echo "Long_CV";
            echo ".pdf' target='_blank'>View my ".$cvtype." CV</a></p>";
            exit();
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<p>Error occurred, kindly try again later.</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
$db_connection->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could share with us  a complete code.

Comment: ill upload the full code now, ive fixed the issue so ill upload how it was fixed incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: @Glenn it would be appreciated to either accept the answer given below, or post a new answer with your fix and accept this so this issue could be marked solved

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in your sql text, there's a 'br' tag.

```
"insert into cv_test(email, fname, sname, cname, usercomment, cvrequested)<br>
                values('$useremail', '$fname', '$sname', '$cname', '$usercomment', '$cvtype');"
```

That was causing the error.

In your new sql test, you have removed the 'br' tag.

```
"insert into cv_test(email, fname, sname, cname, usercomment, cvrequested)
                    values('$useremail', '$fname', '$sname', '$cname', '$usercomment', '$cvtype');"
```

'br' is not part of sql syntax